# Unable to stop the cron job

Tags: unix, cron

I have a cron job in cronjob.txt as follows

```
* * * * * nohup sh cronScheduleInit.sh >> cronlog.txt &
```

and ran it using command,

```
  crontab cronjob.txt
```

After my testing ,i  deleted the cron job entry using following command,

```
 crontab -e
```

and when display the list of jobs using

```
crontab -l
```

showing no entries but still the cron job is running, i mean it is generating the entries in log file. Even i commented the job entry in cronjob.txt file

Also, tried deleting cron job and listed the jobs. its showing no cron jobs but still the log is running...

```
crontab -r
```

What to do.. Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Process** can be find out using command `ps aux`. So check

```
ps aux|grep crontab  #or
ps aux|grep cronjob
```

Then you will get something like

```
user 29587  2.0  1.1 748804 88968 pts/31   Sl+  Mar04  19:55 grunt
```

This result refers for service `grunt`.You have to search `crontab` or `cronjob`

Then kill process using **process id**

Here:

```
sudo kill -9 29587
```

**Format**

```
sudo kill -9 <process_id>
```

Comment: When i tried this, showing error: -bash: kill: (26844) - No such process

Comment: can you show output of `ps aux|grep crontab` or `cronjob`?